# Xfce4 + AwesomeWM. Part of notification area in xfce panel is yanked by AwesomeWM notification area

Tags: xfce, notification-area, awesome-wm, xfce4

I'm using Xfce4 with AwesomeWM (tiling window manager) - xfce takes care of updating, lets me quickly configure new monitor setups (dual head) and so on, while awesome is being awesome at managing windows with minimal configuration :)

The problem is - I still use a small Xfce panel to handle systray/notification area, and during loading some of the notification icons - Gajim, for example - show up in Awesome's notification area. Not a big problem, but it's on the part of one of the screens that I easily miss. After restarting gajim it ends up where I want it.

Now, if I autostart - let's keep Gajim as the example - Gajim via AwesomeWM config, it always ends up in Awesome notification area, while when started via xfce session management, it *sometimes* end up in xfce panel, but not always.

My guess is the loading order - so, how could I force desired loading order in xfce? Or is it some another probloem I haven't considered?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid such problems you should stick to only one notification area. If you want to remove Awesome notification area, edit its config. By default, it's located at `.config/awesome/rc.lua`. If there is no such file, copy it from `/etc/xdg/awesome/rc.lua`.

Find the wibox settings block there:

```lua
    -- Add widgets to the wibox
    s.mywibox:setup {
        layout = wibox.layout.align.horizontal,
        { -- Left widgets
            layout = wibox.layout.fixed.horizontal,
            mylauncher,
            s.mytaglist,
            s.mypromptbox,
        },
        s.mytasklist, -- Middle widget
        { -- Right widgets
            layout = wibox.layout.fixed.horizontal,
            mykeyboardlayout,
            wibox.widget.systray(),
            mytextclock,
            s.mylayoutbox,
        },
    }
```

and remove or comment the line

```
        wibox.widget.systray(),
```